# Boost Fibers Compiler Error (definition of dllimport function not allowed)

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, vcpkg, boost-fiber

With the current version of Visual Studio Community (Version 17.8.6) and the current version of VCPKG (`2023-12-12-1c9ec1978a6b0c2b39c9e9554a96e3e275f7556e`) I have just started getting a compiler error that was not present before.  I verified that with VS Community 17.8.5 and a slightly older cut of VCPKG, this error is not present.

(VCPKG was configured to build with the default `x64-windows` triplet.  Nothing special was done there.  My project is attempting to compile a DLL.)

The full error message is:

```
vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\boost\fiber\stack_allocator_wrapper.hpp(85,43): error C2491: 'boost::fibers::make_stack_allocator_wrapper': definition of dllimport function not allowed
```

This seems to be due to `make_stack_allocator_wrapper` attempting to export a templated function:

From `boost\fiber\stack_allocator_wrapper.hpp`:

```cpp
template <typename StackAllocator, typename ... Args>
BOOST_FIBERS_DECL stack_allocator_wrapper make_stack_allocator_wrapper(Args && ... args)
{
    return stack_allocator_wrapper(
            std::unique_ptr<detail::polymorphic_stack_allocator_base>(
                new detail::polymorphic_stack_allocator_impl<StackAllocator>(std::forward< Args >( args) ... )));
}
```

Has anyone else seen this or determined if this needs patched or otherwise has a way to correct it from client (my) code or CMake configuration?

Comment: dllimport should be a declaration, not definition, it suggests that function is  imported from a dll. Also exporting a template function doesn't make much sense. Templates are instantiated during compile time, not during 'late" dynamic linking. They don't exist otherwise,unless youinstantiate them explicitly

Comment: "The full error message is" - No, this is not full error message. The full error message includes also a **source file** (not a header!) which compilation causes the error.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Header files cause errors, too.  Sure, it is included from a .cpp, but the error is in the header file referenced from boost.  It is the full message, minus the name of the source file that included it, which is redacted and does not add any additional information for the purpose of this question.